# What's "bríos" in the Spanish expression "voto a bríos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos, significado, interjecciones, locuciones

There is a Spanish saying: *¡Voto a bríos!*

[image: ¡Voto a bríos!]

According to the DLE, the word ***[brío](http://dle.rae.es/?id=672nRvF)*** means:

> 1. m. pujanza. U. m. en pl. *Hombre de bríos.*
> 2. m. Espíritu, valor, resolución.
> 3. m. Garbo, desembarazo, gallardía, gentileza.

Nonetheless, the expression *voto a bríos* is registered in the DLE in another, separated entry:

> **[bríos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=678eC06)**
>
> **voto a bríos**
>   1. loc. interj. coloq. p. us. voto a Dios.

What confuses me is that *bríos* and *brío* are separated entries in the dictionary, so is *bríos* a reference to God (as stated by the definition)? Or must *bríos* be understood as in the definition of *brío*? In this case, what of the different meanings of *brío* must be taken?

Comment: Interesting! I had never heard about this saying. _Bríos_ and _Dios_ may sound quite similarly...

Comment: Related but not an answer: "date brío" means "date prisa" (hurry up).

Comment: Hace tiempo encontre una serie de artículos sobre este tema: https://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/anteriores/agosto_11/31082011_01.htm. No acaba de quedar muy claro el origen pero hay alguna cosa interesante.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> BRÍOS, *voto a ~*, es eufemismo por *Dios*, introducido cuando éste aún se pronunciaba *Díos*. *1.ª doc.:* 1525-47, Sánchez de Badajoz.
>     Se dijo también *juro a Bríos* y *por vida de Bríos*. Vid. Munthe, *Juro a bríos baco balillo* (Upsala, 1921) y la reseña de M. L. Wagner, *RFE* X, 404.

<sup>Corominas y Pascual. *Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico.* Tomo I. Madrid, 1984.</sup>

---

In English: `Bríos` is an euphemism for `Dios`, from the time when `Dios` was pronounced `Díos`.

---

**Nota adicional (sólo en castellano):** Irene Cuervo, en [esta interesante serie de artículos](https://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/busqueda/resultadosbusqueda.asp?Ver=50&Pagina=1&Titulo=A%20brios%20rogando&OrdenResultados=2) proporcionada por @blonfu, arguye que la palabra era *brios* con acento en la o (o sea, que se usaba activamente como eufemismo y rimaba con *Dios* pronunciado *Dios*). Los ejemplos que da son bastante convincentes. Esto abre varias posibilidades.

- Se dijo Díos/bríos, después Dios/brios, y, luego de caer en desuso, se recuperó “literariamente” como bríos; o
- Nunca se dijo bríos, fue siempre brios y por alguna razón se le puso tilde en el siglo XX (esto es lo que creo que opina Cuervo); o
- Se dijo Díos/bríos, luego convivieron “voto/juro a bríos” (como frase hecha) y “brios” (como eufemismo); en la literatura quedó “bríos”; o
- Fue siempre bríos, los autores de los versos que cita Cuervo simplemente están usando sinéresis; o
- ...

En fin, parece que el tema todavía tiene mucho para dar. Creo que la respuesta definitiva va a tardar un poco.

Comment: ¡No sabía que Dios en su día se pronunció Díos! ¡Desde luego, así queda mucho más claro el eufemismo!

Comment: En el enlace que puse en un comentario habla de eso también pero al autor de los artículos parece que no le convence ya que las fechas no le cuadran.

Comment: @blonfu: muy interesantes los artículos, gracias. Agregué una nota al respecto.

Comment: ¿Alguien puede explicar el uso de la expresion "vamos, voto a bríos/dios?"

Comment: @aris puede ser una buena pregunta para el sitio, ¿te animas a hacerla?