# ¿Existen palabras plurales que signifiquen algo distinto de sus respectivos singulares?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, plurales, número-gramatical

Es fácil encontrar parejas de sustantivos masculino/femenino cuyos significados evolucionaron en distintas direcciones y terminaron refiriéndose a cosas más o menos distintas. Por ejemplo *suela/suelo, puerta/puerto* y *gorra/gorro*.

Pensé que con el número gramatical ocurría lo mismo en la pareja **la paz** / **las paces**, considerando que el singular se refiere a la "ausencia de guerra", y el plural se refiere a una "reconciliación". Sin embargo, el diccionario me aclaró que el singular también significa "reconciliación", por lo que el ejemplo finalmente no me sirve.

¿Conocen ejemplos de parejas de palabras singular/plural que hayan evolucionado en distintas direcciones hasta significar cosas más o menos distintas? Es decir, palabras que tengan la forma gramatical de plural pero que no signifiquen lo mismo que sus formas singulares.

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22786/12637) puedes ver que "brío" y "bríos" tienen significados tan diferentes que incluso tienen entradas separadas en el DLE, pero creo que este caso ha sido solo un azar del destino, no es que ambas palabras tuvieran un pasado común y sus significados evolucionaran por caminos diferentes, como comentas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existen algunos ejemplos (no perfectos, más bien parecidos al tuyo de paz/paces) como:

- Celo/celos

"[Celo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8A737TG%7C8A7sRXS)" puede tener los significados de "cuidado y diligencia" o "cinta adhesiva", pero "celos" en plural es la envidia a lo ajeno. Incluso para describir el celo (cuidado y diligencia) de varias personas no usarías "los celos de A, B y C". Comparando

> Los *celos* con los que Marta, María y Miranda cuidaban de sus bebés

frente a

> El *celo* con el que Marta, María y Miranda cuidaban de sus bebés

En la primera entendería que se trata de *envidia* (por ejemplo a otra madre que tiene más recursos o ayuda para cuidar de su bebé). En la segunda me queda claro que se refiere a "cuidado y diligencia".

Este por otro lado no es un ejemplo perfecto, ya que "celo" tiene varios significados y para referirte a la cinta adhesiva podrías decir perfectamente "pásame ese celo/pásame esos celos".

- Humanidad/Humanidades

"[Humanidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KnPZIuF)" se refiere a la naturaleza humana, pero "humanidades" se refiere a los ámbitos no científicos del saber como literatura, arte e historia. No te puedes referir a cada una de esas ciencias como una "humanidad" si no al conjunto como "humanidades" aunque de nuevo el ejemplo no es perfecto, ya que "humanidades" puede ser también el plural de "humanidad" como colectivo de la raza humana o conjunto de personas.

- Letra/letras.

Una letra es uno de los símbolos que usamos para escribir, pero "letras" es sinónimo de "Humanidades". De nuevo, el mismo problema. Puedes estudiar una carrera "de letras". Estás forzado a usar el plural. Sin embargo "letras" puede ser también el plural de la letra como símbolo.

Comment: Buena respuesta, Diego. Otros ejemplos podrían ser "tierra" (el material, o el opuesto a "mar") y "tierras" (fincas), "nervio" (conjunto de neuronas) y "nervios" (nerviosismo).

Answer (score 3):

Para responder a tu pregunta, basta con buscar entradas en el diccionario que tengan acepciones marcadas con la abreviatura "pl.", como pasa con la definición de *[humanidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KnPZIuF)*, en la que para las dos últimas acepciones se indica que se debe usar en plural, adquiriendo así un significado distinto:

> 8. f. **pl.** Conjunto de disciplinas que giran en torno al ser humano, como la literatura, la filosofía o la historia.
> 9. f. **pl.** Antiguamente, lengua y literatura clásicas.

Sin embargo, se da el caso de que hay palabras cuyo significado en plural es tan diferente que incluso tienen su propia entrada en el diccionario. Se vio el caso de *brío/bríos*, pero ese lo considero más bien una casualidad. Pero aquí tienes otro más claro:

> **[antojitos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2xd4gJa)**
>
> Del dim. de *antojo*.
>
> 1. m. pl. Méx. Pequeñas porciones de masa de maíz, cocinadas de formas diversas y acompañadas de ingredientes variados.

Esta entrada del diccionario está recogida directamente en plural, y se deriva del diminutivo de *antojo*. Se comprueba pues que el plural de la palabra *antojo* ha sufrido en México una derivación para pasar a significar algo diferente de lo que la palabra en singular expresa (aquí se usa mucho el diminutivo "antojito" para hablar de "antojo" en su acepción de "mancha en la piel de una persona", es decir, de las marcas de nacimiento, sobre todo cuando se las ves a un bebé recién nacido). En todo caso, es cierto que incluso en este caso, se puede hablar de "antojitos" para las marcas de nacimiento si hay más de una.

Buscando en el [DIRAE](http://dirae.es) la marca "pl" encontramos muchos otros ejemplos: *deportivas* ("zapatillas de deporte" en España), *gabrieles* ("garbanzos del cocido", nada que ver con el nombre propio), *asimétricas* ("paralelas asimétricas" en contextos deportivos), *extremadas* ("tiempo en el que los ganaderos están ocupados haciendo queso"), etc.