# ¿Son "ejemplo" y "ejemplos" 2 palabras, o 2 formas de la misma palabra?

Tags: morfología

Estaba leyendo un comentario en una pregunta en el [SE de lingüística](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) y leyendo el artículo [Morfología lingüística](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morfolog%C3%ADa_ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica#Lexemas_(morfemas_l%C3%A9xicos)) . En este último dice:

> Los morfemas gramaticales son las unidades que constituyen la parte variable de la palabra y son las responsables de expresar relaciones gramaticales y que no alteran el significado referencial básico de una palabra.

Esta definición pareciera dar a entender que, en español, "ejemplo" y "ejemplos" serían la misma palabra. Pero aparentemente no en todos los lenguajes es así.

¿Son en español "ejemplo" y "ejemplos" dos palabras, o dos formas de la misma palabra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te sorprendería lo difícil que es definir qué es una [palabra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palabra).

> En gramática tradicional, una palabra (del latín *parabŏla*)​ es cada
>   uno de los segmentos limitados por delimitadores en la cadena hablada,
>   escrita o por señas (...) 
>   Lingüísticamente, el concepto de palabra es mucho más problemático de
>   lo que la definición anterior sugiere. En efecto, determinar qué
>   constituye fonéticamente o morfosintácticamente una palabra es un
>   problema abierto; así, por ejemplo, junto a los morfemas ligados y las
>   palabras léxicas existen los clíticos cuyo estatus de palabra es
>   discutido. En la cadena hablada ordinariamente no existen pausas, y la
>   prosodia es un factor clave para que el oyente perciba la segmentación
>   de palabras de cada frase.

En la mayoría de los casos es conveniente considerar que **el sustantivo es esencialmente igual a su raíz o [lexema](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexema)** y que el singular (representado por el morfema vacío) y el plural (representado por el morfema *-s*, con alomorfo *-es*) no son partes fundamentales de lo que entendemos como "palabra", tanto en un contexto técnico como en la vida diaria. (Una complicación extra es que hay [sustantivos cuyo significado esencial cambia según si están en singular o en plural](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22832/existen-palabras-plurales-que-signifiquen-algo-distinto-de-sus-respectivos-sing).)

Para algunos propósitos es útil considerar que un sustantivo en singular y el mismo sustantivo en plural son palabras diferentes, pero estos casos son los que caen fuera de la morfología: tienen que ver con los efectos fonémicos y fonéticos de la *-s* final de los plurales, con cuestiones de rima y prosodia, o con la mera contabilización de letras en la escritura.

No entro en el análisis de otros idiomas porque no sé bien a qué te estás refiriendo, pero imagino que la cosa se debe complicar en casos como los plurales irregulares del inglés (*man* ~ *men*, *foot* ~ *feet*, etc.) o su pariente, el recurso al *Umlaut* en alemán (*Man* ~ *Männer*, *Fuß* ~ *Füße*, etc.).